# jQuery Unobtrusive Autocomplete not being called

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Unobtrusive autocomplete described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2012/04/23/asp-net-mvc-amp-jquery-ui-autocomplete.aspx) doesn't seem to be called on the Sales/Accounts page of an application I'm building.  I followed advice on this site and elsewhere to reference the autocomplete code to an ActionResult that returns a Json object filled with values for the autocomplete, but the code doesn't seem to even get called because the rest of the page works.  The stored procedure succeeds independently as well.  I'm just learning jQuery, so can anyone spot what's missing here?

Affected parts of View:

```
@model MyProject.Models.AccountsSearchModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Accounts";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Accounts", "Sales", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "accountsForm", autocomplete = "on", data_parsley_validate = "data-parsley-validate"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountName, "Account Name")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AccountName, new { data_autocomplete_url = Url.Action("AutocompleteAccount") })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OwnerName, "Account Owner Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OwnerName, new { data_autocomplete_url = Url.Action("AutocompleteOwner") })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts{

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('*[data-autocomplete-url]')
            .each(function () {
                $(this).autocomplete({
                    source: $(this).data("autocomplete-url")
                });
            });
    });
</script>

<!-- page specific plugins -->
<!-- datatables -->
<script src="/Content/lib/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/lib/DataTables/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/lib/DataTables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/lib/DataTables/extensions/Scroller/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>

<!-- datatables functions -->
<script src="/Content/js/apps/tisa_datatables.js"></script>
}
```

Controller returning "AccountName" Json Autocomplete Object:

```
public ActionResult AutocompleteAccount(string term)
    {
        MyProjectEntities myProjectdb = new MyProjectEntities();

        var items = myProjectdb.uspGetAccountNames();

        var filteredItems = items.Where(
            item => item.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);

        return Json(filteredItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Thanks very much in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Nope, no errors appear and the program never reaches the breakpoint inside the Action Result returning the Json object.  It's as if the autocomplete code is correct but being skipped.  Thanks for the interest, by the way.

Comment: Have you debugged the script - is the `.each()` function being executed?

Comment: Debugging in the browser yields "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined(anonymous function) @ Accounts:455" and "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function(anonymous function) @ Accounts:450n.extend.each @ jquery.min.js:2n.fn.n.each @ jquery.min.js:2(anonymous function) @ Accounts:449n.Callbacks.j @ jquery.min.js:2n.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2n.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:2K @ jquery.min.js:2" in the Chrome Console.  Chrome Sources says "Uncaught TypeError: $(...)autocomplete is not a function."  I'm new to UI - any ideas what they are and how to fix them?

Comment: Why did you say previously that there were no errors in the browser console? Too hard to read in the comments (you should update your question) but it appears firstly that you have not even included `jquery-{version}.js` and/or `jquery-ui-{version}.js` (or may have duplicated them or have them in the wrong order)

Comment: No errors appeared in Visual Studio, and I was unaware Visual Studio wouldn't catch errors appearing in the browser until I researched that idea triggered by your comment.  It appears the jQuery library and folders are included in this project and appearing in the layout file, but like I said, I'm new to UI and will look into those references.  Thank you kindly for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those starting out in UI as I am, here's what solved this problem:

1) AutoComplete is a function of the jQuery UI library that's separate from the default jQuery library.  Download the UI from the jQuery site ([Example](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2013/03/jquery-ui-1-10-2/)) if the files below aren't already in the project.

2)  After adding jQuery UI to the project, make sure "jquery-[version].js" and "jquery-ui-[version].js" are added to or included in the project's Scripts folder.

3)  Reference these files in the scripts section of the page before the AutoComplete code.  Ex:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-[version].js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-[verson].js"></script>
```

4)  At this point, the AutoComplete should work if the Controller code is correct, but the AutoCorrect results are probably transparent.  To make them opaque, add the "all" CSS style sheet to either the _Layout page (if there is one) or the page itself between the head tags.  For additional help on this, Google "mvc autocomplete transparent" and go to the first and fourth (as of this writing) links, entitled "jquery UI controls are transparent | The ASP.NET Forums", and "Bootstrap 3 MVC 5 jQuery-ui Autocomplete - Stack Overflow".  I would post them, but I'm new and currently limited in links per post.